# How to pass parameters with testAction in CakePHP2.0

Tags: cakephp, testing, parameters, phpunit, cakephp-2.0

I want to test a function with this header:

```
public function includeNumComments($posts){
```

Where $post is an array of data.

I wonder how can i test the method passing it an array of posts.

I have tried things like this, but it doesn't work:

```
$result = $this->testAction("/comments/includeNumComments/", array('data' => $posts));

$result = $this->testAction("/comments/includeNumComments/", array($posts));
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not really using `testAction` then, because you can't pass an array via HTTP. There'd be no way to do this via a form or link on a website.

You can just test it as a normal function:

```
$result = $this->CommentsController->includeNumComments($posts);
```

Comment: Ok thanks. Then... i can not get the returned data as "vars", "contents" or "view"?

Comment: My point is that that action wouldn't work as a regular controller action to begin with, because you could never pass an array. If you want it to work as a controller action, you'll need to refactor it to not accept an array. If you were to try it in real life, you couldn't pass an array so it would just fail anyway.

Comment: So... no function on any controller can have an array as a param?

Comment: Not if you want to access it via HTTP (a url). If it's a helper method that's not accessible as an action (like `beforeFilter` for example), then yeah go for it.

Comment: Yeah its ok. This one is not accesible by URL.

Comment: now i have realized i have a problem calling the controller function as you say. 
If that function inside the controller calls another function on a method, (for example, $this->Model->fin("all")) the test crashes and it doesn't execute any more code.

Comment: That sounds like a new problem. You might want to post a new question with details, and describe what "test crashes" means (i.e., PHP fatal error, skips assertions, doesn't run the case, etc).

Comment: It just stops executing code after the call. It doesn't show any error. Just blank.

Comment: Cool, post another question because it's totally different than this one and I'll take a look. This one is technically solved.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the correct case, it worked for me. Hope it helps:

```
public function testAddUser() {
    $data = array(
        'User' => array(
            'id' => 12,
            'username' => 'testname1',
            'password' => 'Pass@123!',
            'email' => 'test@example.com'
        )
    );
    $result = $this->testAction(
        '/users/add',
        array('data' => $data, 'method' => 'post')
    );
    debug($result);

}
```